# google place sample app showing invalid api even though everything has been added properly

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api

Currently I am facing a problem running google places api demo app from [GitHub](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-places) repo . After cloning the repo I have replaced the API with a certified debug Key . but demos are not working for example all intent based google places activities are being closed after calling . Even there is no error on debugger . For the [PlaceCompleteAdapter](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-places/tree/master/PlaceCompleteAdapter)project there is a toast message showing says "Error contracting API : status INVALID_API_KEY " although everything has been added properly !!! What is going on here ? Plz someone help me out

Comment: It would be nice if your your manifest.xml file , once I had faced the same issue . I was wondering if you are doing the same mistake

Comment: @vutkaBilai sure thing . `<manifest 

    <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.geo.AIzaSyDHHCtvKUHzcjw41gY0LZmDEoS8T_N0EhM"
                android:value="AIzaSyDHHCtvKUHzcjw41gY0LZmDEoS8T_N0EhM"/>
</manifest>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@PuchkaIndur I found what you are doing wrong 
you are passsing wrong key value for the meta data tag .

`<meta-data
      android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
      android:value="YOUR_API_KEY"/>`
    [see the Doc](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/start)

```
N.B never expose
```

your API_KEY like this publically .hope this will solve your issue , if not let me know